# MongoChef Aggregation: In one query find and show average score for max 3, 2 and 1 'project month' grouped data

Tags: mongodb

Using MongoChef aggregation, if you have data such as:

```
{_id: 1, Mnt: 2016-05-01, Score: 85}
{_id: 2, Mnt: 2016-05-01, Score: 85}
{_id: 3, Mnt: 2016-03-01, Score: 80}
{_id: 4, Mnt: 2016-03-01, Score: 80}
{_id: 5, Mnt: 2016-03-01, Score: 80}
{_id: 6, Mnt: 2016-01-01, Score: 75}
```

and want to:

1. Calculate max month in the collection (i.e. M1 : May 2016),
2. Group by "Mnt" - which might not be sequential latest months, e.g. collection above latest/largest 3 months being: 2016-May, 2016-March, 2016-January,
3. Find the latest X month totals,
4. Calculate the Average of each,

e.g.

```
{M1 : 85, M2 : 82, M3 : 80.8}
```

I.e. 
M1 is average of max month in collection,
M2 is average of max 2 project months in collection
M3 is average of max 3 project months in collection  etc.

Comment: The type of the `Mnt` field will not make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

this is a dirty solution, but will give you an overview how to start:

```
var i = 1;
var elemSum = 0;
var elemCount = 0;

db.a.aggregate([{
            $group : {
                _id : {
                    year : {
                        $year : "$Mnt"
                    },
                    month : {
                        $month : "$Mnt"
                    }
                },
                avg : {
                    $avg : "$Score"
                },

                elemCount : {
                    $sum : 1
                },
                elemSum : {
                    $sum : "$Score"
                }
            }
        }, {
            $sort : {
                "_id.year" : -1,
                "_id.month" : -1
            }
        },
        {
            $limit : 3
        }, // first 3 records


    ]).forEach(function (doc) {

    elemSum += doc.elemSum;
    elemCount += doc.elemCount;
    var result = elemSum / elemCount;
    var x = "M" + i.toString() + ": ";
    print(x + result.toString());
    i++;

})
```

and I converted month field to iso time

```
db.a.insert([
{_id: 1, Mnt: new ISODate("2016-05-01T15:44:00.255Z"), Score: 85},
{_id: 2, Mnt: new ISODate("2016-05-01T15:44:00.255Z"), Score: 85},
{_id: 3, Mnt: new ISODate("2016-03-01T15:44:00.255Z"), Score: 80},
{_id: 4, Mnt: new ISODate("2016-03-01T15:44:00.255Z"), Score: 80},
{_id: 5, Mnt: new ISODate("2016-03-01T15:44:00.255Z"), Score: 80},
{_id: 6, Mnt: new ISODate("2016-01-01T15:44:00.255Z"), Score: 75}

])
```

Answer (score 0):

Code that works - calculate a running 12-month and current month Net Promoter Scores:

```
   db.Collection.aggregate(

// Pipeline
  // Stage 1
{
  $project: {
        ID: "$ID",
             Mnt: "$Mnt",
             CntryReg: "$CntryReg",
             Prom: "$Prom",
  }
},

// Stage 2
{
  $group: {
            _id: '$Mnt',
            docs: {
                $push: {
                    Mnt: "$Mnt",
                    CntryReg: "$CntryReg",
                    Prom: "$Prom"
                }}

  }
},

// Stage 3
{
  $sort: {
      _id: -1
  }
},

// Stage 4
{
  $limit: 12
},

// Stage 5
{
  $group: {
         "_id": null,
         "values": { "$push": "$docs" } 

  }
},

// Stage 6
{
  $unwind: {
    "path": "$values", "includeArrayIndex": "rank"  
  }
},

// Stage 7
{
  $unwind: "$values"
},

// Stage 8
{
  $project: {
      _id: 0,
         Mnt: "$values.Mnt",
         CntryReg: "$values.CntryReg",
         Prom: "$values.Prom",
         rank: "$rank"

  }
},

// Stage 9
{
  $group: {
          _id: {CntryReg:"$CntryReg"} ,

          AR12: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $eq : ["$Prom", "D"]}, 1, 0]} },
          Ind12: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $eq : ["$Prom", "I"]}, 1, 0]} },
          Loy12: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $eq : ["$Prom", "P"]}, 1, 0]} },
          Sum12: {$sum: 1 },

          AR1: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $and : [{  $eq : ["$Prom", "D"]} ,  {$eq : ["$rank", 0]} ]}, 1, 0]} },   
          Loy1: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $and : [{  $eq : ["$Prom", "P"]} , {$eq : ["$rank", 0]} ]}, 1, 0]} },
          Ind1: { $sum: { $cond :  [{ $and : [{  $eq : ["$Prom", "I"]} , {$eq : ["$rank", 0]} ]}, 1, 0]} },
          Sum1: { $sum: { $cond :  [ {  $eq : ["$rank", 0]}, 1, 0]} },
```